# Calling a function in js file from C# code

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am having a cs file where I want to call the function of js file.

Js File

```
Function foo(date){
//code
}
```

In a cs file, I want to call the foo function. Is it possible ? If yes, then how ?

If I want to insert just one alert then this is how I do it, but If I want to call a function, then I dont know the way.

To call just an inline javascript this works

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "", "<script type='Text/JavaScript'> alert('Hello');</script>");
```

Comment: Calling `alert` is calling a function.  What are you trying to do exactly and what issue are you having?

Comment: @RickS When I write `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "", "foo()", true);` , it shows "Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"","foo()",true);"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the function name rather than the whole script itself.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"","foo()",true);
```

or with ScriptManager:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),"","foo()",true);
```

Edit:

Add the boolean value at the end to `true`, so it will automatically add script tags, then you dont need to.

Comment: It shows "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: it works if there is no argument in the foo function, but if I have a date parameter passed, then how can I pass it with the code `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"","foo()",true)`. It works if there is no argument.

Comment: can I see how you are passing the arguments.

Comment: `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "a", "foo("aa","bb")", true);` Foo has 2 arguments in the function.

Comment: Moreover, I am trying to make a loop(when I try with 0 arguments) and it runs only 1 time, why does this happen ?

Comment: as for the why the arguments aren't working, is because you are passing them in wrong. If aa and bb are variables  `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "a", "foo("+aa+","+bb")", true);` If not you can just do `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "a", "foo('aa','bb')", true);`

Comment: Moreover, I am trying to make a loop(when I try with 0 arguments) and it runs only 1 time, why does this happen.

Can you have a look at this : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926593/for-condition-running-only-once-when-calling-js-file)

Comment: the problem is not one or two variables, it is how they are being used. `foo(' " + hello + " ', ' " + wor + " ');"` without the single quotes, it thinks that `hello` and `wor` are javascript variables and looks for those variables in the `<script>` tags. Since they are declared and initialized in C# we need to pass them as strings to the javascript function.