# For condition running only once when calling JS File

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am running a Javascript from c# code.

```
  for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
   {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "a", "foo("hello")", true);
   }
```

Js File

```
Function foo(a){
alert(a);
//some other logic
}
```

Here, the problem is when i debug the code, i can see loop going for 3 times, but the alert appears only once.

Why does it appear only once ? How can I solve this ?

Comment: You need to register different names.

Comment: @SLaks When I try with this code it does not run at all. Can you tell me how should I run with different name ?
`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "("+i+")", "foo(" + i + ")", true);`

Comment: Check the generated source.  But that probably isn't a legal name.

Comment: @SLaks I did not understood what you meant. COuld you explain properly or give an example pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Lloyd said is correct, the `+ i` is necessary to make unique pairs.

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "a"+ i, "foo('hello');", true);
}
```

You were missing the semicolon at the end of the javascript function.

This is what was being generated with what @Lloyd suggested

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
foo("hello")foo("hello")foo("hello")//]]>
</script>
```

And this is what you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
foo('hello');foo('hello');foo('hello');//]]>
</script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're registering the startup script three times with the same key, from MSDN:

> A startup script is uniquely identified by its key and its type.
>   Scripts with the same key and type are considered duplicates. Only one
>   script with a given type and key pair can be registered with the page.
>   Attempting to register a script that is already registered does not
>   create a duplicate of the script.

The startup script itself will just run once.

For example, see what happens when you do this instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "a" + i, "foo(\"hello\")", true);
}
```

Comment: the function is not called at all now.

Comment: no your edited version also does not call the function even once.